# wp_editor save all content

Tags: code

Sorry my english is very poor.

I have create a new y theme for wordpress, and create new category for user download, but in the backend(admin) i have add wp_editor(), in subcategory, but when i save changes, not save all the changes,only save text, no save the images.

i don´t know if is because i have used get_option for save the data, or i need save in database and after restore to see in fronted, in area user(client).

thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I solve part of this problem.

Comment: I solve part of this problem.i have add `stripslashes()` when i get the content         , `$content = stripslashes(get_option("Living_registrado"));`
but not get shortcode, and return the data, no respect the space,<br>,the words and images appear one after the other,`, if i haven´t put in html,  .thanks.